# Running jobs in Gitlab in a sequence

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to add dependency amongst job belonging to same stage ?
like i have 3 jobs in one stage , but would like to run them one after another in a sequence and not parallel.

Comment: No, you can't do that. If you want to create dependencies, you need to put jobs in different stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should configure your runner not to run concurrent jobs: [gitlab doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html)

try the tag `concurrent = 0`